# Cycles on AMD takes abnormally long time to render

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, gpu, opencl

Since I upgraded to the latest version of OS X and Blender 2.76, I was looking forward to finally being able to use GPU acceleration with my AMD card. Instead, using the BMW benchmark scene, it is now at the 48 minute mark and only about 2/3 done rendering. Most of that time the system seems to be frozen. If I remember correctly, the same render took me 3 minutes using the CPU. I have a Radeon R9 M395X with 4GB of RAM. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: The opencl support that allows gpu rendering is not 100% complete yet. The R9 M395X is not listed in [supported cards list](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/OpenCL) and [OSX El Capitan is needed for OSX amd support](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Ref/Release_Notes/2.76/Cycles). You may be interested in contacting one of the developers with your specs and offering to test and provide feedback on your hardware.